# How to use React error boundary with promises

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, react-router, react-hooks

I'm trying to implement generic error page for any unhandled exceptions in React application. However, it seems like the error boundary doesn't work with exceptions thrown by promises such as API operations. I know I could catch the exception at component level and re-throw it at the render method. But this is boilerplate I would like to avoid. How to use error boundary with promises?

I'm using latest React with hooks and react-router for navigation.

Answer (score 1):

You can do by creating a HOC which will take two parameters First one is the component and second the promise. and it will return the response and loading in the props Please find the code below for your reference.

HOC

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
function withErrorBoundary(WrappedComponent, Api) {
  return class ErrorBoundary extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { hasError: false, response: null, loading: false };
    }
    async componentDidMount() {
      try {
        this.setState({
          loading: true
        });
        const response = await Api;

        this.setState({
          loading: false,
          response
        });
        console.log("response", response, Api);
      } catch (error) {
        // throw error here
        this.setState({
          loading: false
        });
      }
    }
    static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
      // Update state so the next render will show the fallback UI.
      return { hasError: true };
    }

    componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
      // You can also log the error to an error reporting service
    }

    render() {
      if (this.state.hasError) {
        // You can render any custom fallback UI
        return <h1>Something went wrong.</h1>;
      }

      return (
        <WrappedComponent
          response={this.state.response}
          loading={this.state.loading}
          {...this.props}
        />
      );
    }
  };
}
export default withErrorBoundary;
```

How to use HOC

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import withErrorBoundary from "./Error";

class Todo extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log("this.props.response", this.props.response);
    console.log("this.props.loading", this.props.loading);
    return <div>hello</div>;
  }
}
const Comp = withErrorBoundary(
  Todo,
  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1").then(response =>
    response.json()
  )
);

ReactDOM.render(<Comp />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Please check the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-jlinv) for your refrence